Dual booting with windows and ubuntu, want to install ubuntu on other SSD?
I have 2 SSDs, 1 TB ssd has windows installation and another 256 GB SSD for ubuntu (I want to install on it, not installed). I have a bootable flash drive ready for the installation. So, on the step where I have to select options like install with windows bootloader, wipe windows and install ubuntu and manual boot. I am stuck here.
So, I want to use only 256 GB SSD for the installation purpose. I don't want to damage any data on my 1 TB drive. When proceeding with the bootloader option I am getting this message to disable bitlocker protection, but since I want to only install on 256 GB SSD why do I disable it?
For last option, I select the 256 GB SSD and it automatically shows an entry in the table with ubuntu bootloader installed. But on that menu the next button is diabled and I can't move ahead.
Since I want to install Ubuntu of 256 GB SSD why do I need to disable bitlocker protection?
Please help me with any solutions.
Thanks

You state, "I don't want to damage any data on my 1 TB drive." A laudable desire! Before making any major change to the system, make, and verify, a full drive image (not simply an OS or data backup), in case something goes wrong. You can always restore your data and OS from that image.

Apparently it's because the installer is trying to be "consumer/layman friendly" (or "safe", so it claims). Also, you probably have picked the wrong option as well.
If you want to use a dedicated disk for the installation, you can/should really choose wipe drive (I'm pretty sure the word wasn't Windows) and install. Note that dedicated disk refers to a disk, not a partition / volume / drive in the sense of "C: drive", that has nothing you need to keep on it, including but not necessarily limited to any kind of user data and any kind of system partition the Windows installation you want to keep (that is mainly on the other disk) might have placed on this disk. If you don't have the ability to confirm that, then stop reading my answer. No guarantee or warranty for your data.
The reason is obvious. As you said yourself, you are just trying to install it to the smaller disk. If there's nothing on it that needs to be kept, certainly you can let the installer just "wipe drive and install". (NOTE: Neither the chance that you pick the wrong drive in the process, nor that the installer is bugged that it disregard your choice and work on e.g. the first disk enumerated anyway, is low. Therefore, often it is suggested that one can disable the disk in BIOS/UEFI setting if possible, or even physically remove it temporarily if not. However, at the same time there are often counter-suggestions, which is somewhat legit, since many layman like to "stay blind", break things, and yell afterwards, "when deal with low level stuff". So make your own call.)
The option you have picked, which apparently is Installing Ubuntu alongside another operating system, to be precise, apparently allows shrink your Windows installation if it is not encrypted. Probably because the Ubuntu devs think that it would look bad if you are given a draggable slider / "divider" that isn't draggable, or that they could be so lame that they end up having coded an installer that is worse than Windows' and somehow got you to delete your Windows installation when it is encrypted, they decided to forbid you from picking this option and in turn picking a blank disk that might be available (which should lead to same result as the "erase and install" option).

One possible solution is to disable the Bitlocker encryption first.
After disabling Bitlocker, it can take anywhere from minutes to hours to decrypt the drive completely.
The hard drive and its data will be visible and accessible from the Ubuntu installer at this point, allowing it to correctly and safely set up a side-by-side configuration.

Remove your 1tb SSD. Install only the 256gb SSD. Boot from your usb. Install Ubuntu on the only option it will have for you, the 256gb, and rest easy knowing there’s no way your 1tb will be affected even if computer is possessed and hellbent on destroying windows OS.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
